# Sull'origine e significato di 'bollinatura'

Tags: grammar

Sapreste dirmi quale sia l'origine e il significato di 'bollinatura', di cui qui sotto vedete un esempio d'uso?

Inoltre, oltre a quello che ne fa il MEF, conoscete altri contesti in cui si usi? Per esempio, è ammissibile dire 'Oggi ho impostato il master plan, domani devo bollinarlo'?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Direi che e' un termine  'burocratese', non di uso comune.

[Bollinare](http://www.sapere.it/enciclopedia/bollinare.html): (da Sapere.it)

> - v. tr. [sec. XX; da bollino]. Apporre determinati bollini per rinnovare un documento, per dimostrare la validità di un certificato e simili: bollinare la patente. Per estensione, convalidare mediante un qualunque contrassegno: bollinare una tessera, una ricetta mutualistica.

[Bollinare](http://archiviostorico.corriere.it/1994/giugno/25/Zzz_ultimo_confine_dell_italiano_co_0_94062513120.shtml): (da Archivio Corrire Sera- 1994)

> - Proprio nei giorni scorsi, ha fatto la sua comparsa sui giornali un verbo di cui i dizionari, e nemmeno gli "Addenda" del Treccani, registrano l' esistenza. Si tratta di un verbo che appartiene al linguaggio della Ragioneria Generale dello Stato, la quale, quando critica un documento governativo ma finisce con il dare l' approvazione, lo "bollina", indicativo presente di un "bollinare" che appartiene ai cieli imperscrutabili della burocrazia.

Comment: +1, ma secondo me né corsera né sapere.it ci prendono per come bollinare è usato in quel comunicato MEF.